# css/html how to make logo appear after heading

Tags: html, css

I want to add a logo to a header after the heading. Right now the logo image is below the heading. I also have a navigation in header.

This is my css code related to header and logo.

```
#header {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #33CCFF;
}

#logo {
    display: inline;
    width: 71px;
    height: 46px;
    background-image: url(resources/images/logo.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

html file

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"> 

<div id="logo">
  <h1>iSHOP</h1>
    <img  src="resources/images/logo.jpg" width="71" height="46" />
         </div></div> 



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The CSS doesn't help if we don't have the HTML or an image to go off of: we can't read your mind.

Comment: i have mapped it with html. you want html file?

Comment: Seeing as you've tagged this question with HTML, that would certainly be useful.

Comment: Or you could JSFiddle it :D

Comment: @Aibrean While JS Fiddle is most definitely helpful, note that the code should still be posted with the question in order to avoid issues like link rot blocking people from seeing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change you css to point to the h1 tag.  Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e6dNm/)

```
#logo h1 {
   //styles here
}
```

You were pointing at the h1 container, so it was still displaying as a block level element